# Using DCMTK - DICOM-Toolkit 3.6.0 - dcmdump.exe failed?

Tags: images, data-dump

Using DCMTK - DICOM-Toolkit 3.6.0 Win - dcmdump.exe failed with DVT Images.

```
D:\dcmtk-3.6.0-win32-i386\bin>dcmdump -M -L +Qn -Un dicom-dvt-image-file
```

Output like this

```
    =================[OUTPUT]=====================================================================
W: DcmItem: Length of element (ffff,000d) is odd
E: DcmElement: Unknown Tag & Data (ffff,000d) larger (1313013767) than remaining bytes in file
E: dcmdump: I/O suspension or premature end of stream: reading file: dicom-dvt-image-file
```

What kind of DICOM Image Type (0008,0008) is this..?
Any hint?

EDIT

With Option " - E" I get

```
========================================================
W: DcmItem: Length of element (ffff,000d) is odd
E: DcmElement: Unknown Tag & Data (ffff,000d) larger (1313013767) than remaining bytes in file
E: dcmdump: I/O suspension or premature end of stream: reading file: 6.1180118095212400.122.a000

# Dicom-File-Format

# Dicom-Meta-Information-Header
# Used TransferSyntax: Unknown Transfer Syntax

# Dicom-Data-Set
# Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Implicit
(ffff,000d) ?? (not loaded)                             # 1313013767, 1 Unknown Tag & Data
```

With option "-d" I get

```
D: $dcmtk: dcmdump v3.6.0 2011-01-06 $
D: 
D: DcmItem::checkTransferSyntax() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Implicit"
D: DcmItem::checkTransferSyntax() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Implicit"
W: DcmItem: Length of element (ffff,000d) is odd
E: DcmElement: Unknown Tag & Data (ffff,000d) larger (1313013767) than remaining bytes in file
E: dcmdump: I/O suspension or premature end of stream: reading file: 6.1180118095212400.122.a000
```

Looks like TransferSyntax: **Little Endian Implicit** is the problem.

*P.S. I moved this question from Stack Overflow* 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508699/using-dcmtk-dicom-toolkit-3-6-0-dcmdump-exe-failed

EDIT 1

try with dcmtk 3.6.3

```
D: $dcmtk: dcmdump v3.6.3 2018-02-05 $
D: 
D: DcmFileFormat::lookForXfer() no MetaInfo found
D: DcmDataset::read() trying to detect transfer syntax of data set (because it is unknown)
D: DcmDataset::read() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Implicit"
W: DcmItem: Length of element (ffff,000d) is odd
E: DcmElement: Unknown Tag & Data (ffff,000d) larger (1313013767) than remaining bytes in file
W: DcmItem: Invalid Element (ffff,000d) found in data set
E: dcmdump: I/O suspension or premature end of stream: reading file:
```

EDIT 2

Take a closer look with makhaon DICOMDUMP I get this "error"

```
Detect if file is of Part10 format and detect encoding...
Read Preamble and DICOM Prefix..
DICOM Prefix ("DICM") not found; file is probably not of Part10 format
Try to parse file as non-Part10 file...
read DICOM Prefix ("DICM") at begining of file
DICOM Prefix ("DICM") is not found at the begining of file
Detect Encoding (Big Endian or Little Endian) by reading Group Number of first Element..
EDICOMParseError: Group number of first Element is larger than 0008
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to dump the DICOM file with dcmdump from the latest DCMTK release, i.e. version 3.6.3, but to me it looks like the file is no DICOM file (file meta information is missing).

Could you make the binary file available for further analysis?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Ok, I will download DCMTK 3.6.3 and try again. This file contains personal information, so I can't upload it. Maybe we get a working viewer in some days or the files is defect.

Comment: Understood, but could you post a hexdump of the binary file, e.g. with "hexdump -C". The first lines would be sufficient, i.e. you could cut off the dump where the Patient's Name (0010,0010) appears.

Comment: Currently I can't find a good HEXDUMP program here with me. Opened with an editor (NetBeans IDE) the result is clearly different from a correct DICOM image. At the very front of the defective picture is: ...CNNTImg...

Comment: Ok, I cancle this test and wait a little bit. maybe we get new correct images. Have a look at EDIT 2.

Comment: OK, I would also guess that the file is not a proper DICOM image (see my first comment on StackOverflow). If you work under Windows, you might find this hex editor useful: https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/